# I'm trying to insert an 'array' of 'objects' into a html table

Tags: javascript

```
var table_data = [ 
                 { first_name : 'Rose', last_name : 'Tyler', home : 'Earth' },
               { first_name : 'Zoe', last_name : 'Heriot',home : 'Space 
                  Station W3'},
               { first_name : 'Jo', last_name : 'Grant', home : 'Earth'},
               { first_name : 'Leela', last_name : null, home : 
               'Unspecified'},
               { first_name : 'Romana', last_name  : null, home : 
                'Gallifrey'},
               { first_name : 'Clara', last_name  : 'Oswald', home : 'Earth'},
               { first_name : 'Adric',last_name  : null, home : 'Alzarius'},
               { first_name : 'Susan', last_name  : 'Foreman', home : 
              'Gallifrey'}
            ];

for (prop in table_data ){
    document.write(prop , ':' , table_data[prop]);
}
```

I'm looking to put this data into a table. How would I insert this into a HTML 'table'.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `document.write()`, which is a very old way of putting data into a page and has very limited use cases today. Instead, follow modern DOM standards and create the elements in memory, configure them and then append them into the document.

See the comments in the code below:

```js
var table_data = [ 
   { first_name : 'Rose', last_name : 'Tyler', home : 'Earth' },
   { first_name : 'Zoe', last_name : 'Heriot',home : 'Space Station W3'},
   { first_name : 'Jo', last_name : 'Grant', home : 'Earth'},
   { first_name : 'Leela', last_name : null, home : 'Unspecified'},
   { first_name : 'Romana', last_name  : null, home : 'Gallifrey'},
   { first_name : 'Clara', last_name  : 'Oswald', home : 'Earth'},
   { first_name : 'Adric',last_name  : null, home : 'Alzarius'},
   { first_name : 'Susan', last_name  : 'Foreman', home : 'Gallifrey'}
];

// First, prepare the table
var tbl = document.createElement("table");

// Loop through the main array
table_data.forEach(function(o){
  
  // For each object in the array, we need a new row
  var r = document.createElement("tr");
  
  // Now, loop over each object's properties
  for (var prop in o){
    // Each property will need to go into a cell
    var c = document.createElement("td");
    c.textContent = o[prop];  // Populate cell
    r.appendChild(c);         // Place cell in row
  }
  
  // Place row in table
  tbl.appendChild(r);
  
});

// Place table in document
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

```css
table { 
  border:1px solid grey;
  width:50%;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:aliceblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dataToTable(data) {
  const table = document.createElement("table")
  for (let item of data) {
    const row = document.createElement("tr")
    for (let value of Object.values(item)) {
      const td = document.createElement("td")
      td.textContent = value
      row.appendChild(td)
    }
    table.appendChild(row)
  }
  return table
}

var table_data = [{
    first_name: 'Rose',
    last_name: 'Tyler',
    home: 'Earth'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Zoe',
    last_name: 'Heriot',
    home: 'Space Station W3 '
  }, {
    first_name: 'Jo',
    last_name: 'Grant',
    home: 'Earth'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Leela',
    last_name: null,
    home: 'Unspecified'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Romana',
    last_name: null,
    home: 'Gallifrey'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Clara',
    last_name: 'Oswald',
    home: 'Earth'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Adric',
    last_name: null,
    home: 'Alzarius'
  },
  {
    first_name: 'Susan',
    last_name: 'Foreman',
    home: 'Gallifrey'
  }
];



document.body.appendChild(dataToTable(table_data))
```